# Custom snippets.json with Emmet - was working now it doesn't

Tags: emmet

I created a custom snippets.json for emmet that added [snippets for ExpressionEngine code](https://bitbucket.org/CreateSean/ee-emmet-snippets). This was working great for several weeks. Then one day without having made any changes to the file it has stopped working. I have uninstalled/installed emmet several times, have reset paths for extensions_path and even tried using prior working versions of the file but all to no avail.

I've got the file sitting in dropbox so that I can use it on my laptop and desktop. Has stopped working on both computers. Am completely flummoxed about why this mysteriously stopped working when there was no change between one day and the next.

Any thoughts on how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://bitbucket.org/CreateSean/ee-emmet-snippets/src/678a6cd775fbd9b3573d4b1e2a149df47c7c2f11/snippets.json?at=master) file is not a valid JSON since it contains comments.

In previous versions Emmet simply eval’ed configs to make such things as comments work but I had to switch to JSON parser to make Emmet CSP-compliant (required by many browser-based editors).

Comment: Oh... thanks for the info. will remove comments and try again.